# How do I integrate $I = \int_0^\infty dr \: r e^{-ar^2}$, $a \in \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I know that the answer has to be $\frac{1}{2a}$, $Re(a) > 0$. I tried using partial integration and I am left with
$I = -\frac{e^{-ar^2}}{2a} \bigg\rvert_0^\infty + \int_0^\infty dr \frac{e^{-ar^2}}{2ar}$,
where the first term already gives me the desired result. Is my calculation up till now correct? How can I argue that the second term vanishes, even though the integral seems to be divergent?

Comment: I am not sure how you got that equality by integration by parts. What is true is that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} dr \, re^{-ar^2} = \left[ -\frac{e^{-ar^2}}{2a} \right]_{r=0}^{\infty} = \frac{1}{2a}. $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial integration isn't the way to go here. Instead, use $u = r^2$, so $du = 2r\, dr$ and $\frac{1}{2} \, du = r \, dr$.

$$\begin{align}I &= \int_0^\infty r e^{-ar^2} \,dr\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty e^{-au}\,du \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left[-\frac{1}{a}e^{-au}\right]_0^\infty \\
&= \frac{1}{2a}
\end{align}$$
where the final limit $u \to \infty$ is valid since $Re(a) > 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint remark that the derivative of $e^{-ar^2}$ is $-2rae^{-ar^2}$.

Comment: Perhaps you forget an $a$ factor